# How to customise the PostgreSQL/psql prompt?

Tags: postgresql, command-line, customization

How can I customize the prompt in the PostgreSQL command line tool psql (ideally in a per-user start-up script)?

In particular, I'd like to be able to change it while still including the character that indicates whether the command is multi-line (eg. `=`, `-`, `'`, etc.).

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid),  PostgreSQL 8.4.4.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can certainly [customize](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PROMPTING) the prompt.

From the documentation:

> The prompts psql issues can be
> customized to your preference. The
> three variables `PROMPT1`, `PROMPT2`, and
> `PROMPT3` contain strings and special
> escape sequences that describe the
> appearance of the prompt. Prompt 1 is
> the normal prompt that is issued when
> psql requests a new command. Prompt 2
> is issued when more input is expected
> during command input because the
> command was not terminated with a
> semicolon or a quote was not closed.
> Prompt 3 is issued when you run an `SQL COPY` command and you are expected to
> type in the row values on the
> terminal.

If you want to set the prompt on a per user basis, you can add the `\set` commands to the user's `.psqlrc` file.

So, your `$HOME/.psqlrc` would be something like this:

```
\set PROMPT1 '(%n@%M:%>) %`date +%H:%M:%S` [%/] \n%x%# '
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like the multi-line indication character I mentioned is `%R`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also customize the prompt at the command line, if you can't setup a `$HOME/.psqlrc` file (e.g shelling into a container you don't control)

```
$ PROMPT1="PROMPT1='%[%033[1;31;40m%]%/%R%[%033[0m%]%# '" 
$ psql -v $PROMPT1
```

Or if you are connecting to a container via kubectl, you can do something like so:

```
  POD=$(getPodThatHasPostgresCli)
  PSQL_PATH="./pgsql/bin/"
  PROMPT1="PROMPT1='%[%033[1;31;40m%]%/%R%[%033[0m%]%# '" 
  CMD="export PGPASSWORD='$PGPASS'; $PSQL_PATH/psql -v $PROMPT1 $PGURL -U $PGUSER $*"
  
  if ! kubectl exec -it "$POD" -- /bin/bash -c "$CMD"
  then
    echo "failed to connect to psql in pod"
    exit 1;
  fi
```