# Setting the psql prompt on the command line?

Tags: postgresql, psql, prompt

As per [How to customise the PostgreSQL/psql prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804130/how-to-customise-the-postgresql-psql-prompt) the psql prompt can be set by `\set PROMPT1 foo`.

How can I set the prompt on the command line?  This incantation sets ZZZ but not PROMPT1.

```
psql --set=ZZZ=abc --set=PROMPT1=foo ...

postgres=# \set
PROMPT1 = '%n%R%#%x '
ZZZ = 'abc'
```

Comment: works for me.  Maybe it has something to do with your OS or shell or version, or what is hidden behind the `...`

Comment: Or maybe your .psqlrc overwrites the settings with its own value.

Comment: @jjanes Yes, it was .psqlrc.  If you want to create an answer I'll accept it.